# Output signal for space-state

Tags: control-systems

I have a space-state system and I need to find the output signal of it. Can anyone here explain to me how to do it?
[image]

My soluation: is it a right answer?
[image]

Comment: Hi Tornedoar and welcome to DSP.SE. While we can't provide solutions to homework / quiz / test problems, we're happy to help if you show your work and what you already researched. Let us know what you already understand, and what might be confusing  you, from the course material provided.

Comment: I found the transfer function of this module and then did the inverse laplace so I got the y(t), is it a true method?

Comment: Please update your question to show what you did.

Comment: @DanBoschen I just did.

Comment: Yes this looks right. Do you really just need to find the output only at t=0?

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your time.